# Oracle SQL*Loader getting CDATA values

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, loader, sql-loader

Anybody knows how to do this?  I know there's a better way of loading XML data to Oracle without using SQL*Loader, but I'm just curious on how this is done using it.  I have already a code that can load XML data to the DB, however, it wont run if the XML file has values that contain a CDATA...

**Below is the control file code which works if the values are not CDATA...**

```
LOAD DATA  
INFILE FRATS.xml "str '</ROW>'"  
APPEND  
INTO TABLE "FRATERNITIES"  
(  
    DUMMY FILLER TERMINATED BY "<ROW>",  
    THE_CODE SEQUENCE (MAX, 1),  
    DUMMY2 FILLER TERMINATED BY "</COLUMN>",  
    STORE_NN_KJ ENCLOSED BY '<COLUMN NAME="THE_NAME">' AND '</COLUMN>',  
    STAFF_COUNT ENCLOSED BY '<COLUMN NAME="THE_COUNT">' AND '</COLUMN>'  
)
```

**Here's the XML file:**
`<?xml version='1.0'  encoding='MS932' ?>

   <RESULTS>

    <ROW>

        <COLUMN NAME="THE_CODE">777</COLUMN>

        <COLUMN NAME="THE_NAME">CharlieOscarDelta</COLUMN>

        <COLUMN NAME="THE_COUNT">24</COLUMN>

    </ROW>

</RESULTS>`

**Here's the XML file with CDATA values.  My control file will not run with it...:**
`<?xml version='1.0'  encoding='MS932' ?>

   <RESULTS>

    <ROW>

        <COLUMN NAME="THE_CODE"><![CDATA[777]]></COLUMN>

        <COLUMN NAME="THE_NAME"><![CDATA[CharlieOscarDelta]]></COLUMN>

        <COLUMN NAME="THE_COUNT"><![CDATA[24]]></COLUMN>

    </ROW>

</RESULTS>`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
STORE_NN_KJ "substr(substr(:STORE_NN_KJ,instr(:STORE_NN_KJ,'<![CDATA[')+9),0,instr(substr(:STORE_NN_KJ,instr(:STORE_NN_KJ,'<![CDATA[')+9),']]>'))" ENCLOSED BY '<COLUMN NAME="THE_NAME">' AND '</COLUMN>'
```

*EDIT*
Looks like I forgot a ).. Try this..

Comment: Hello sir! Thanks for the prompt reply.  I tried your code today but it doesn't work.  There's an error:
`SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 9.
Expecting valid column specification, "," or ")", found keyword enclosed.`